# Solution verification: Spivak Calculus Chapter 11 exercise 58

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, slope

Hoping to get some verification on this proof.

Calculus by Michael Spivak, 3rd Ed. Chapter 11, exercise 58:

> **58.** Use the method of Problem 57 to prove that if $n$ is even and $f(x) = x^n$, then every tangent line to $f$ intersects $f$ only once.

Here's the referenced exercise:

> **57.** (a) Let $y \neq 0$ and let $n$ be even. Prove that $x^n + y^n = (x + y)^n$ only when $x=0$. Hint: If $x_0^n + y^n = (x_0 + y)^n$, apply Rolle's Theorem to $f(x) = x^n + y^n - (x+y)^n$ on $[0,x_0]$.
>
> (b) Prove that if $y \neq 0$ and $n$ is odd, then $x^n + y^n = (x+y)^n$ only if $x = 0$ or $x = -y$.

My proof is a little different than the one in the Answer Book, so I was hoping someone could look it over and see if it's ok.

**58. Solution**

We have $f(x) = x^n$ (where $n$ is even).

Let's assume the tangent line to $f(x)$ at some point $(a,a^n)$, intersects $f(x)$ at another point $(b,b^n), b\neq a$.

This tangent line has slope
$$f^\prime(a) = na^{n-1}$$

$f(x)$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ so the Mean Value Theorem tells us there exists some point $c$ in the interval $(a,b)$ such that
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
but this is just $f'(a)$.

In other words, we have

$$f'(c) = f'(a)$$
$$nc^{n-1} = na^{n-1}$$
$$c^{n-1} = a^{n-1}$$

Because $n-1$ is odd, this is only possible if $c = a$, a contradiction. So our assumption that $b$ exists such that $(b,b^n)$ is intersected by the tangent of $f$ at $(a,a^n)$ must be wrong.

Comment: Well, you didn't justify your conclusion. Spivak justifies it by saying that $x^m$ is increasing when $m$ is odd (which is easier to do with derivatives than it is to supply a proof of your assertion by a tricky exercise in Chapter 1). At any rate, the proofs are essentially equivalent.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I've done that Chapter 1 exercise so I'm allowing myself to use it here without re-proving it.

Comment: That's cool, @Ben. You should just refer to it for completeness. In general, it's good math form to quote a result that's already been established. But you should refer to it so that the reader knows how you're reasoning.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps especially important when soliciting help here, where folks maybe don't have the book or any idea what I might or might not know or be allowed to assume. It's such an early result in the book I just kinda take it as given now. Spivak is funny that way: skip the wrong problems and you might miss out on some pretty important results. Best not to skip any!